# C# JSON Parsing Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, parsing

Hi I am currently doing my final year project and nearly at the end. However, I am stuck on one small thing which is parsing the below JSON string in C#.

My Bad... copied and pasted an excerpt from the JSON file. Here is the whole JSON string which is valid when I checked jsonutils.org

```
{ 
    "activities-steps" : [ 
        { 
            "dateTime" : "2016-02-10",
            "value" : "2624"
        } 
    ],
    "activities-steps-intraday" : { 
        "dataset" : [ 
        { 
            "time" : "00:00:00",
            "value" : 0
        },
        { 
            "time" : "00:01:00",
            "value" : 0
        },
        { 
            "time" : "00:02:00",
            "value" : 0
        },
        { 
            "time" : "00:03:00",
            "value" : 0
        },
        { 
            "time" : "00:04:00",
            "value" : 0
        },
        { 
            "time" : "00:05:00",
            "value" : 0
        },
        { 
            "time" : "00:06:00",
            "value" : 0
        },
        { 
            "time" : "00:07:00",
            "value" : 0
        },
        { 
            "time" : "00:08:00",
            "value" : 0
        },
        { 
            "time" : "00:09:00",
            "value" : 0
        },
        { 
            "time" : "00:10:00",
            "value" : 0
        },
        { 
            "time" : "00:11:00",
            "value" : 0
        },
        { 
            "time" : "00:12:00",
            "value" : 0
        },
        { 
            "time" : "00:13:00",
            "value" : 0
        },
        { 
            "time" : "00:14:00",
            "value" : 0
        },
        { 
            "time" : "00:15:00",
            "value" : 0
        },
        { 
            "time" : "00:16:00",
            "value" : 0
        },
        { 
            "time" : "00:17:00",
            "value" : 0
        }
        ],
        "datasetInterval" : 1,
        "datasetType" : "minute"
    }
}
```

I need the value of the dateTime in the first JSON object and then the values of the time and value items in the second object. I have implemented the below code however it keeps on giving me a `NullReferenceException`.

These methods are used in order to help parse the JSON objects

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Activity activity { get; set; }
    public ActivityGranular activity_granular { get; set; }
}

public class Activity
{
    public string dateTime { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

 public class ActivityGranular
{
    public List<ActivityGranularDatapoint> dataset { get; set; }
    public int datasetGranularity { get; set; }
    public string datasetGranularityType { get; set; }
}

public class ActivityGranularDatapoint
{
    public string time { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}
```

MainCode in the Main Class which when executed returns null in both root elements in the root objects class above and gives a `NullReferenceExceptions`

```
resultsJSON.Replace("-", "_");

root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(resultsJSON);

activity = root.activites_steps;
activityGranular = root.activities_steps_intraday;

for (int a = 0; a < activityGranular.dataset.Count; a++)
{
    activityGranularDatapoint[a].time = activityGranular.dataset[a].time;
   activityGranularDatapoint[a].value = activityGranular.dataset[a].value;
}
```

All help is much appreciated :)

Comment: How are you posting the data? Can we see the AJAX call and the endpoint either WebAPI or in your controller?

Comment: Nevermind - misunderstood what you're doing.

Comment: I am using HttpRequest to the Fitbit API and storing the response in a WebResponse variable. I am then using a Stream reader to read the response string into the resultsJSON string

Comment: I want to read the dateTime value in the first object and then iterate through every time and value item in the second object

Comment: At which line are you having the NulReferenceException?

Comment: At this line due to the fact that both activity and activityGranular are being set to null. I think it is a problem deserializing the JSON object into root

Comment: @JakeAzzopardi have you seen my answer ? If you have another solution let us know about it?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `JsonProperty` attribute if the name of a property into your json doesn't respect your needs. Just don't use:

- a workaroung or hacking the json data.
- don't replace any content of the json
- Let it as it is.

The below code just work by renaming properties of your classes as follow

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("activities-steps")]
    public List<Activity> ActivitesSteps { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("activities-steps-intraday")]
    public ActivityGranular ActivitiesStepsIntraday { get; set; }
}

public class Activity
{
    [JsonProperty("dateTime")]
    public string DateTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class ActivityGranular
{
    [JsonProperty("dataset")]
    public List<ActivityGranularDatapoint> DataSet { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("datasetInterval")]
    public int DatasetInterval { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("datasetType")]
    public string DatasetType { get; set; }
}

public class ActivityGranularDatapoint
{
    [JsonProperty("time")]
    public string Time { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that the fields in the json need to match exactly to the Class's fields. 
for example, `RootObject`
should look like:

```
class RootObject{
public List<Activity> activitiessteps
public List<Dataset> activitiesstepsintraday
//and so on..
}
```

Dataset should be:

```
class Dataset {
public List<Activity> dataset
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The objects definitions and JSON do not match, and the [Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx) method is not correct.

```
// Replace does not replace the values in the original variable, 
// it returns a string representing the original with the replaced values,
// so you must reassign it to a variable as such.

resultsJSON = resultsJSON.Replace("-", "_");
```

Assuming you are using the Newtonsoft.Json library, to resolve your issue with matching the signatures it is possible to use the [DataContract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attributes to rename your class properties without using the [Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

As such the following modifications will resolve the null issue based on the JSON you provided.

```
[DataContract]
public class RootObject
{
    [DataMember(Name = "activities-steps")]
    public Activity[] activity_steps { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "activities-steps-intraday")]
    public ActivityGranular activity_granular { get; set; }

}

public class Activity
{
    public string dateTime { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class ActivityGranular
{
    public List<ActivityGranularDatapoint> dataset { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "datasetInterval")]
    public string datasetGranularity { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "datasetType")]
    public string datasetGranularityType { get; set; }
}

public class ActivityGranularDatapoint
{
    public string time { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}
```